# ng-bind-html - get image via filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm currently working on a module where users can enter text into a text-area, along with some image-tags which have the following format:

`ii[5ae71206|100|100]ii`.

This is how I 'm showing the text entered:

```
<span ng-bind-html="localeCache[item.sysName][editLocale]['text1'] | imageFilter"></span>
```

The "imageFilter"-filter is supposed to replace my custom tag from the text with an `<img>`, so `ii[5ae71206|100|100]ii` becomes:

```
<img src="path-to-file-with-image-id-5ae71206" 
     style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px;">
```

The source code for my filter is as follows:

```
define(
    ['angularAMD', 'docService']
    , function(angularAMD){
        angularAMD.filter('imageFilter', function($rootScope, DocAdminService){
            return function(text) {

                var regExImgTag = /ii\[(.*?)]ii/g;
                var regExImg = /ii\[.*?\]ii/;
                var imageTags = regExImgTag.exec(text);

                if(imageTags !== null){
                    var tag = imageTags[1];
                    var parts = tag.split('|');
                    var imgTag = parts[0];
                    var width = parts[1];
                    var height = parts[2];

                   var imgString = '<img ng-src="' + $rootScope.path_to_REST_Service + imgTag + '" style="max-width:' + width + 'px; max-height:' + height + 'px;">';
                   var textNew = text.replace(regExImg, imgString);
                   console.log(textNew);
                    return (textNew);
                    });
                }
                else{
                    return text;
                }
            };
        });
    }
);
```

The filter DOES return the correct string, but the view isn't rendering the image. When I'm just entering some text without my custom image-tag, everything is working as intended.
Any ideas?

Comment: Try to replace `src` with `ng-src`

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. Didn't change the behaviour.

Comment: Is it typo: `var imgString` -> `$rootScope.path_to_REST_Service'`    `'` after _Service

Comment: Oh, sorry, no. That was just a leftover tick from editing the code before posting. Edited my post. Thanks for the keen eye, though ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I think I located the problem: I do have a REST-service call inside my filter, which I removed for my initial post, since I thought it wasn't important and would only confuse people:

```
define(
    ['angularAMD', 'docService']
    , function(angularAMD){

        angularAMD.filter('imageFilter', function($rootScope, $sce, DocService){
            return function(text) {

                var regExImgTag = /ii\[(.*?)]ii/g;
                var regExImg = /ii\[.*?]ii/;
                var imageTags = regExImgTag.exec(text);

                if(imageTags !== null){
                    var tag = imageTags[1];
                    var parts = tag.split('|');
                    var imgTag = parts[0];
                    var width = parts[1];
                    var height = parts[2];

                    DocService.listDocsByParameters({ firstParam: 'textPropertyC/s/eq/' + btoa(imgTag) }, function(response){
                        var imgId = response[0].id;

                        var imgString = '<img src="' + $rootScope.restUrl + 'doc-rest/documentById/' + imgId + '" style="max-width:' + width + 'px; max-height:' + height + 'px;">';
                        var textNew = text.replace(regExImg, imgString);
                        console.log(textNew);
                        return textNew; //This is probably the problem.
                    });
                }
                else{
                    return text;
                }
            };
        });
    }
);
```

I solved this by adding another array to my controller, which maps the image tag to the image-id, which I need to get the proper image from the REST-service. This array will be passed to the filter:

```
<span ng-bind-html="localeCache[item.sysName][locale]['text1'] | imageFilter:imageMap"></span>
```

The filter then looks like this:

```
define(
    ['angularAMD']
    , function(angularAMD){

        angularAMD.filter('imageFilter', function($rootScope){
            return function(text, map) {

                if(typeof map === 'undefined' || typeof text === 'undefined' || text === '' || text === null){
                    return text;
                }

                var regExImgTag = /ii\[(.*?)]ii/g;
                var regExImg = /ii\[.*?]ii/;
                var imageTags = regExImgTag.exec(text);

                if(imageTags !== null){
                    var tag = imageTags[1];
                    var parts = tag.split('|');
                    var imgTag = parts[0];
                    var width = parts[1];
                    var height = parts[2];

                    var imgId = map[imgTag];

                    var imgString = '<img src="' + $rootScope.restUrl + 'doc-rest/documentById/' + imgId + '" style="max-width:' + width + 'px; max-height:' + height + 'px;">';
                    var textNew = text.replace(regExImg, imgString);
                    console.log(textNew);
                    return textNew;
                }
                else{
                    return text;
                }
            };
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use plain `src` attribute since ng-src will need to $compile the HTML again. Here is a similar working example.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngSanitize"]);
app.controller("MainController", function($scope){

  $scope.localeCache = "Some text";

});

app.filter("imageFilter", function(){
    return function (input) {
    
        //Here you add modifications to the input.
        //This is just an example
        
        var width = "100px",
            imgPath = 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
            height = "100px";
        
        return '<img src="' 
        + imgPath
        + '" style="max-width:'
        + width 
        + 'px; max-height:'
        + height 
        + 'px;">';
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.5.1/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">
  <span ng-bind-html="localeCache | imageFilter"> </span
</div>
```

Comment: I initially had a plain "src" there, so that unfortunately isn't the problem. I'm guessing by now there must be something else going wrong in my app, which is preventing the filter from working. If I copy the output that my filter produces directly into the user input, it's working...

Answer (score 0):

I wrote simple demo with filter that works for me:

```
<div ng-bind-html="path | imageFilter" ></div>
```

*JS*

```
app.filter('imageFilter', function($sce){
            return function(text) {
              var html = $sce.trustAsHtml('<img src="' + text  +'" style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px;"/>'); 
               return html;
            };
        });

app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.path = 'https://media.mnn.com/assets/images/2014/09/running-with-dog.jpg.653x0_q80_crop-smart.jpg';
});
```

[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HbuHR5PoTFBqvbw1Ynxh?p=preview)

So problem inside filter logic

Comment: Aren't you basically bypassing the filter-aspect here? When I copy your logic from the controller to the filter, the example doesn't work.

Comment: @DCH why you want to use filter? filter main job is to filter list by condition. I would write all filter logic into `link` of directive